# What does this selector do in jquery?

Tags: jquery

What does this selector do in jquery:

```
$('tr[parents*=x'+1111014+'x]');
```

Thanks

Comment: The expression selects all `tr` elements that have a `parents` attribute with `x1111014x` anywhere in the `parents` attribute value. There's no reason why that can be written as `$('tr[parents*=x1111014x]');` unless you're using a variable.

Comment: The concatenation seems unnecessary.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: I'm using a variable, just put a number for demostration porpuses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will select any element of the following form:

```
<tr parents='asdfsx1111014xasdfsa' >
<tr parents='x1111014xasdfsa' >
<tr parents='asdfsx1111014x' >
<tr parents='x1111014x' >
```

Basically any `tr` tag, with a `parents` attribute. And the `parents` attribute should contain the following: `x1111014x`.

See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) on jQuery select-contains.

Comment: BTW the attribute name is non-standard, which means some browsers may ignore it. Should better use `data-parents` name for that attribute. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for more.

Answer (score 5):

Lets break it down;

- `tr` will select all the `<tr>` elements.
- `[parents]` will select all the elements with attribute `parents`
- `*=` is the *[contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)* selector, it will do a match on the following string.

So the selector `'tr[parents*=x1111014x]'` will select all the `tr` elements on the page which have an attribute that contain the string `x1111014x`.

For example:

```
<tr parents="xxxx1111014xxxxxx">
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the `Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]`. It means find all tr elements that contain an attribute `parents` containing 'x1111014x'

As @PeterKA points out `*=` is for selecting element attributes.
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

As @JosephMarikle mentioned in the comment 'contains' means that any part of the selectors value can contain 'x1111014x'. So this selector would match all of the following: `'x1111014x'` ,`'FOOx1111014xBAR'` ,`'FOOx1111014x'`, `'x1111014xBAR'`

Comment: but what means the expression parent*  ??

Comment: the `*=` indicates anywhere in the attribute.  beginning with (`^=`) and ends with (`$=`) are also options.  `*=` will match `34x1111014x4` for example.

Comment: I think you meant the [**Attribute Contains Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

The break down (for easier understanding):

`'tr[parents*=x'+1111014+'x]'`

- `tr` is a `<tr>` tag.
- `[]` square brackets indicate an attribute selector (eg `class`, `style`, etc)
- `parents` is the attribute to find
- `*=` means that the attribute value `must contain the following string`
- `x'+1111014+'x` would be equated to a string `"x1111014x"`

So, all in, it would look for a `tr` tag that has an attribute `parents` which contains the string `x1111014x`

Some examples of matching elements would be:

```
<tr parents="x1111014x">
    <td>Hello World</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr parents="helloworldx1111014x">
    <td>Hello World</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr parents="hello x1111014x world">
    <td>Hello World</td>
</tr>
```